# How to redirect dhcp (Linux)

Tags: linux, dhcp, redirect

I have a linux DHCP server which I need to redirect all web traffic to a landing page which will have instructions on how to register their computer on the network.

No matter what URL a user types in, the user needs to be redirected to a webpage (on the DHCP server).

ie: user types google.com they are immediately redirected to 192.168.10.1. This DHCP server will never be used to access the web. Once the user acquires the instructions to register their computer from the landing page, they will be blacklisted on this particular DHCP server and forced to request an IP from the main DHCP server.

How can I create such a redirect?

Comment: Copied without attribution from [DHCP Server to Redirect any url to landing page](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10331408)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a captive portal. See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal.
There are open source solutions that do just that. Lookup captive portal open source on google.
Note that the DHCP server assigns  IP address and, mask, gateway, DNS config parameters. The captive portal needs to be implemented in the router box so as to prevent any trafic to the Internet until the user opens a web session and authenticates.